# Having ASP.NET MVC partial view without creating a new file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there a way to have the partial view code directly inside the main view? I got code in a view that is repeating but I don't want to create a new file for the partial view. I could see it work like a section

```
@inlineview Test {
   <b>Some Text</b>
}

@RenderInlineView("Test")
...
@RenderInlineView("Test")
...
@RenderInlineView("Test")
```

Comment: _"I got code in a view that is repeating "_ Can you show us the relevant code?

Comment: I think you might want Razor helpers `@helper Test{}` to reuse code in a view and you can invoke with `@Test()`

Comment: @phuzi this does exactly what I needed. With the ability to add parameters is even better than what I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a block of code (incl. HTML) you want to reuse, you can use Razor helpers.

```
@Test()

@Test()

// Helpers
@helper Test(){
    <b>Some Text</b>
}
```

Would result in

```html
    <b>Some Text</b>

    <b>Some Text</b>
```